# Why does this lifetime not "expire"?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

For the following block, when do the lifetimes `'b` and `'c` end?

```rust
use core::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<'b, 'c, T> {
    child_b: &'b T,
    child_c: &'c T
}

impl<'b, 'c, T> A<'b, 'c, T> {
    pub fn new_wrapper(b_value: &'b T, c_value: &'c T) -> A<'b, 'c, T> {
        A {
            child_b: b_value,
            child_c: c_value
        }
    }
}

fn doesnt_drop_borrow<T: Copy>(ty: &T) {
    *ty;
}

fn drop<T>(ty: T) { }

fn main() {
    let b: String = "wonderful".into();
    let c: String = "lifetime".into();
    let a = A::new_wrapper(&b, &c);
    println!("hello this {:?} world", &a);
    doesnt_drop_borrow(&a.child_c);
    drop(a.child_c);
    println!("hello this {:?} world", &a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `a.child_c` has the type `&String`, the `ty` parameter in
`doesnt_drop_borrow(&a.child_c)` has type `&&String`, and
`*ty` has type `&String` so the original `String` (`c`) won't
be dropped.

I don't know what precisely motivates your question but I guess
it's the fact that you can still use `a` after calling `drop(a.child_c)`.
The name of this function is misleading because the `ty` parameter here
has type `&String` (the same as `a.child_c`).
So the `ty` parameter appears as a new immutable borrow of the original
`c`, then is immediately dropped, but the original `c` is not dropped.
When a reference is dropped the referred to value is not.

None of these two functions actually move the original `String`,
they only deal with references.

So `b` and `c` here live till the end of `main()`, and so does `a`
which contains references to them.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `&T` is `Copy`, so `drop(a.child_c)` drops a copy of `a.child_c` (i.e. `a.child_c` is not moved).

Comment: @FrancisGagné: There is even a [clippy lint (`drop_copy`)](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#drop_copy)  for that.

Comment: Well, in this particular case it would be [`drop_ref`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#drop_ref), I think.